# Few questions regarding Angular directives

Tags: angularjs

I have few questions regarding angular directives

I'm basing my questions based on the following block of codes

```
<ul class='parent'>
    <li class='child1'></li>
    <li class='child2 active'></li>
    <li class='child3'></li>
</ul>
```

So based on the above

- How can i create a directive based on the above (assuming this comes from an Angular plugin, and there is no angular directive attribute defined within the tag)?
- Assuming the above is from an Angular plugin, and i don't intend to edit the plugin, how can i use the directive to see which list is currently active?
- How can i do operations through the code above using Angular? With Jquery, i can easily do it as

For checking the child length

```
$('.parent').children().length
```

For iterating through the child elements

```
$.each($('.parent').children(), function(){ console.log(this); });
```

But when i tried to do it with Angular way

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.parents')).children().length
```

Somehow this part always returned me the wrong value. I guess my Jquery mindset is the reason why i couldn't get the value but still, i read somewhere that angular.element object is the equivalent of the jquery $() object, thus both should be able to use the same functions.

- If i want to do event binding on the code above i should do it inside the link function correct? If i want to watch and apply changes for the code above, then i should use the directive's scope and do it inside the link function too right?
- Is there easy-to-chew guide on how Angular's directives? Somehow most of those that i read are pretty much as confusing as the directive guide in Angularjs documentation itself.

Comment: If you are using an angular plugin, the plugin should expose an API for you to get/set the active item (is this carousel, btw?)

Comment: Its not carousel, and unfortunately, the plugin is pretty limited (newly developed, has no usable callbacks, and hard to manipulate with Angular (at least for me))

Comment: Then why use the plugin?